# Употребление словосочетания "грамотный профессионал"

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Правильно ли говорить: **грамотный профессионал?**

Comment: Вот ещё шедевр на эту тему -"федеральный договор"

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос не нов, но для ответа контекст нужен.

Тут вот какая штука. В таком сочетании, если оно корректно, оба этих слова скорее всего должны использоваться не в основном значении. Основное не годится ни для одного из слов. **Грамотность** в прямом значении давно не есть значимая характеристика кого бы то ни было, она всеобщая. А для использования сочетания "грамотный профессионал" в историческом или каком-то ещё специфическом контексте (кроме уголовного и спортивного) не годится  прямое значение слова **"профессионал"**, поскольку оно означает сейчас прежде всего не просто профессионального работника, но мастера своего дела.

Поэтому, если контекст реально предполагает прямое значение хоть одного из слов, то использование сочетания "грамотный профессионал" или неправильно, или умышленно небрежно, подчеркнуто авторский стиль. 
Судя по поисковым запросам, именно такое сочетание ("грамотный" - переносно, "профессионал" - прямо) порождает основные стилистические ошибки.

С другой стороны, в нацкорпусе находится несколько примеров, пусть и не особо авторитетных авторов, иного использования.

> Поэтому мы привлекаем в комитеты Союза всех грамотных, уважаемых
>   профессионалов ― участников строительного комплекса. [Елена
>   Колесниченко. «Строители должны объединить свои усилия!» (2003) //
>   «Пермский строитель», 2003.12.19] [омонимия не снята] ←…→
>
> Представьте себе ситуацию: молодого инженера Н. С. Васькина,
>   отработавшего всего год на предприятии, но показавшего себя грамотным
>   профессионалом и талантливым руководителем, назначают техруком ЖБК-1.
>   [Надежда Костяева. По жизни — главный инженер (2003) // «Пермский
>   строитель», 2003.06.05] [омонимия не снята] ←…→
>
> Но грамотному профессионалу крутиться можно, вот и Сергей крутится,
>   хотя человек он, конечно, препоганый. [Ольга Некрасова.
>   Платит последний (2000)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Здесь, несмотря на кажущуюся кому-то тавтологичность, использование сочетания выглядит вполне корректным (как минимум в первых двух примерах), поскольку оба слова использованы ***не в прямом значении***.

Вывод. Использование сочетание можно признать стилистически корректным, если по контексту автор предполагает использование ***обоих*** слов не в первом значении.

Добавлю только, что подобные вопросы стилистики всегда решаются с долей субъективности, поэтому всё сказанное - личное мнение.

(=========)

И в качестве самостоятельной реплики. Комментарий к не разделяемому мной мнению о тавтологичности, которое часто присутствует в обсуждениях этого вопроса.

Ощущение тавтологичности у некоторых критиков идет, видимо, от смешения понятий. В использованном (в вышеприведенных примерах) значении имеем следующее.

[**Профессионал**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB) - хороший специалист.

[**Грамотный**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) - Обладающий необходимыми знаниями, сведениями в какой-л. области; знающий.

Да, похоже. Но если в первом случае говорится **об умениях, навыках**, то во втором, очевидно, - **о знаниях**. А это принципиально разные вещи. И чем квалифицированнее, технологичнее отрасль, о которой идет речь, тем существеннее разница между просто хорошим работником, и работником грамотным - знающим, способным ещё и **управлять** организацией своего и чужого труда.
Я так это понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения грамматики - да, так как они сочетаются в роде, числе, падеже.

С точки зрения семантики и стилистики - только если речь о профессионале, владеющем грамотой.

Иначе получается избыточность значения на грани тавтологии.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "грамотный профессионал" в Нацкорпусе    встречается редко, то есть можно предположить  **несочетаемость или ограниченную сочетаемость** этих слов.

**ПРОФЕССИОНАЛ**,  м. Тот, кто сделал какое-л. занятие, деятельность своей профессией. Охотник-профессионал.  // **Хороший специалист**. В автоделе это настоящий п. Ведь ты п., а рассуждаешь, как дилетант.

**ГРАМОТНЫЙ**, 1. Умеющий читать и писать; умеющий писать грамотно, без ошибок. Г. человек. Г. ученик. Г-ое сочинение.  2. **Обладающий необходимыми знаниями, сведениями в какой-л. области; знающий**. Г. инженер.

Таким образом,  специалист,  по определению, **всегда грамотный** и знающий в своей области человек, поэтому мы говорим, к примеру, грамотный инженер, или хороший  специалист, или профессионал своего дела.

На слух выражение "грамотный профессионал" **не кажется корректным, потому что воспринимается в первом значении этого слова ―  работник определенной профессии, хотя это слово имеет второе значение** ― хороший специалист.

**Возможные определения**: хороший профессионал, настоящий/истинный профессионал, профессионал высочайшего класса и т.д. То есть класс специалиста оценивается по тому, насколько он **хороший** специалист.

Comment: Встречается. Как минимум три случая: 2,3 и 8. http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E3%F0%E0%EC%EE%F2%ED%FB%E9+&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=5&lex2=%EF%F0%EE%F4%E5%F1%F1%E8%EE%ED%E0%EB&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=

Comment: Встречается, конечно, но не часто, обычно: грамотный специалист, профессионал.

Answer (score 0):

Корректность употребления этого сочетания зависит от контекста. Очевидно, что "**грамотный**" в данном сочетании возможно только в переносном смысле (речь не может идти о владении чтением и письмом). Понятие же "**профессионал**" само по себе употребляется в двух значениях:

**1. Прямое значение**: человек, для которого рассматриваемое занятие является профессией, основным источником средств.

**2. Оценочное значение**:

a) "истинный профессионал" (и аналогичные оценочные выражения) - *хороший специалист* из числа профессионалов (в прямом смысле), ведущий себя адекватно ("профессионально") в ситуациях, связанных с профессией (например, врач, готовый в любое время дня и ночи помочь больному; персонаж Бельмондо в фильме "Профессионал" - он до конца выполнял полученное задание, по канонам профессии);

б) человек, умеющий что-то делать настолько хорошо, как будто это его профессия ("бабуля у нас просто профессионал по части тортов").
Усилиями журналистики второе, переносное значение за последние десятилетия потеснило первое, но полностью его, конечно, не уничтожило - с ним по-прежнему нужно считаться как с прямым значением.

Если исходить из этих двух определений, то в сочетании с оценочным пониманием профессионализма эпитет "грамотный" (здесь: *умеющий что-то делать хорошо и правильно*) воспринимается как излишество, поскольку "профессионал" в оценочном смысле (*хороший специалист*) включает в себя его смысл.

"Грамотным" может быть напр. нанятый по случаю работник, который владеет навыками, которых требует данная работа, и применяет правильные приёмы, характерные для профессиональных работников этой области. Такой работник может быть или не быть профессионалом в прямом смысле (во втором случае он подрабатывает в свободное от основной профессии время). Соответственно, в первом случае он -**"грамотный профессионал"**, в отличие от представителей данной профессии, которые не вполне ей владеют. Поэтому сочетание с прямым значением слова "профессионал" можно представить себе в такой ситуации:

> -- У нас проблемы с трубами, давай позовём того сантехника, Васю.
>
> -- Нет, он в прошлый раз не на лён поставил кран, а ленту накрутил - будто не знает, как надо. И мужа тети Тани тоже не будем звать - он
>   всё-таки дилетант. Нам нужен **грамотный профессионал** - не просто
>   профессиональный сантехник.